# Gradient of a complex function.

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Function 
$$(,)=2 − i\cdot ^2^3.$$

I need to perform some operations on this function, starting with finding its gradient.

One way would be to take the partial differential of the function w.r.t $x$ and ignore the partial wrt to $y$. In that case the outcome would come out to be:

$$2y - 2ixy^3$$

Is this approach correct?

Furthermore i need to calculate, the divergence of the given function. How would i go about that?

Answer (score 3):

1. You should apply the definition directly:
   $$\nabla f(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}\partial_x f(x,y)\\ \partial_y f(x,y)\end{pmatrix}.$$
2. Yes, indeed, your partial derivative with respect to $x$ is correct.
3. Again, the definition of divergence is all you need.

Comment: so the divergence comes out to be :: 2y - 3$x^2$$y^2$.

Comment: thanks for the help but i further need to calculate the curl and laplacian. But the problem with calculating curl is that i need to first calculate the cross product of the function with partials of x y and z however cross product on works in 3 dimension and this function is in 2?

Comment: You can artificially add the third dimension, find the cross-product, then keep the only non-zero component: to find $curl \, (h(x,y),g(x,y))$ take $ \nabla_{x,y,z} \times (h(x,y),g(x,y),0)$ and keep only the third component.

Comment: Or otherwise just apply the definition $curl \, (h,g) = \partial _x h - \partial _y g$